# Database under heavier load -- all SQL queries start timing out after a period of hours/days

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-timeout, performance-tuning

I make a web application which has experienced heavy growth in the past week and it appears my database is seizing up because of it.

[image]

You can see that everything seemed to be OK until about 3AM this morning and then all of my requests started timing out. This isn't the first time this has happened, but after I push new changes to the server it starts up OK again. It doesn't seem to happen under low load, but has also ran at high load for hours perfectly fine. I don't think 3AM is an especially high load time.

Things I have done / to note:

- Dedicated server, MSSQL and I'm using NHibernate as an ORM to generate my queries.
- The server is pretty much just a data store. 99% of the queries are very basic insert/selects. I have one bulk insert for creating a large amount of playlist items.
- I have batching enabled. It is set to 50 by default and 200 if >1000 playlist items are about to be  written to the database. This reduced the spikes in my DB's response times.
- I have my command timeout set to 5 seconds. It was set at the default, 30 seconds, and I was still experiencing the issue. The problem seems to have stayed away for a longer period of time after setting it to 5 seconds.
- I have tried running `exec sp_updatestats` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation# which did show some indexes being updated, but did not result in any real differences.
- I have set my databases connection isolation level to ReadUncommitted: `configuration.SetProperty("connection.isolation", "ReadUncommitted");`
- I specify the default DB for NHibernate performance as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100499/what-does-hibernate-default-schema-mean): `configuration.SetProperty("default_schema", "[db896d0fe754cd4f46b3d0a2c301552bd6].[dbo]");`

What on earth should I be looking at to try and get a grip on what is causing my database to lockup? It's showing only 1% CPU usage so I don't think it is overly taxed. It shouldn't be a long running query if I have 5 second caps on everything. It's not the indexes. I'm running out of ideas.

In terms of queries -- it's all SELECT user statements. It's just a bunch of people trying to login and access their account. I'm getting about 1000 requests / 30 minutes for SELECT user.

Here's some more info:

[image]
[image]

@@VERSION:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4270.0 (X64)   Nov 30 2012
>   17:11:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit)
>   on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: So do you have scheduled jobs that start at 3:00 AM (like index rebuilds, defrag, backups, etc.)? Keep in mind that response time is rarely associated with CPU - more likely it is I/O.

Comment: No. There's nothing scheduled, it's a completely clean server that is spun up by AppHarbor: https://appharbor.com/ It's just got the handful of tables on 1 DB on it. The 3 AM death time I don't think is super special. It died on me at 4PM a couple of days ago and then came back up once I restarted everything. And yeah, it says 1% CPU usage so I don't think it's that!

Comment: If this is hosted somewhere, you might want to ask the host what happens on this server at 3 AM. It could be their maintenance interfering with you, or a "noisy neighbor." Keep in mind that a noisy neighbor doesn't necessarily have to be on the same server as you - could relate to SAN or network overhead.

Comment: Well, that's what I would've thought when used a shared instance, but I'm on dedicated now so I wouldn't expect that to be the case. Nevertheless, I'll write them.

Comment: Couple of things, check what queries are running at a specific time using Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive stored proc, http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx

That could tell you if you are dealing with locking/blocking or other waits.

Also, check your waits to see what the bottleneck is. Brent Ozar has a great query for that here, http://www.brentozar.com/responder/triage-wait-stats-in-sql-server/. That should also let you know specifically what bottlenecks you are facing.

Comment: I thought that if I set my read level to uncommitted that I couldn't have locking/blocking/other waits? Or am I misunderstanding? Nevertheless, I'll look into both links. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't but Read Uncommitted still requires a schema lock so there is a possibility that if your query can't obtain a schema lock, that it could be blocked. However, I doubt that is your issue. More  likely that you are waiting on something like storage.

Comment: I'll ramp the worker power and see if that resolves it -- maybe its the power of the server if i'm not waiting on DB locks..

Comment: Ha! `It's showing only 1% CPU usage so I don't think it is overly taxed.` The graph you've added tells a different story. It's not completely CPU-bound, but it's a far cry from 1%. How's recompilation? Is all the hibernate junk ad hoc SQL? Do you have the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` setting enabled? What version of hibernate? @@VERSION of SQL Server?

Comment: I've updated with the version. I agree the graph tells a very different story. What do you mean by "How's recompilation" and "ad hoc SQL" ? Sorry for my naivety, I can go read about the terms.

Comment: Aaron means, are you using Stored Procedures that can be cached or are all the SQL statements you run 'ad-hoc' SQL, that is not cached and therefore the query has to be recompiled each time you run it? This adds overhead to each request.

Comment: There's no sprocs. It's just some simple ad-hoc SQL, as you say. 96% of my server load is just GET requests of users trying to login to an empty account.

Comment: Dont know if you have solved the issue yet.
I had the same problem (i think) and tracked it down to faulty Citrix NIC drivers on the cloud server. Since you use AppHarbor you are hosted on amazon, where I had the problem. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting indices on my PKs, but I did not have indices on my FKs. Most of my queries were of the form: "Select Playlists p where p.UserId = 'XXX'"

Even though I had an index on User's ID, I did not have one on Playlist's UserID. This was root cause.